# Invert ground vs. open "signal" - relay?

Tags: switches, relay, ground, automotive

first post here.

I'm trying to design a circuit to invert a ground/open input signal. I.e., output is grounded when the input is open, and vice versa.

I have a feeling this can be accomplished with a relay - but could be mistaken.

Specifically, this is to resolve an issue in my car's instrument cluster - I've upgraded to a nicer cluster, and everything works, except that the ABS light functions backwards - i.e., on when it should be off, and off when it should be on. I've confirmed this behavior by comparing the results of various tests between the two clusters.

As far as I know, the ABS computer controls the light by grounding a particular wire (I know which wire it is). With this wire cut, I now have an "ABS side" and a "lamp side". In order to reverse the behavior, I was considering the following circuit:

85: 12V from ignition
86: ABS side (states are either open or grounded)
87: N/C
87A: Lamp side
30: Ground

If I have understood correctly, this would mean when the ABS side is open, the lamp side is grounded, but when the ABS side is grounded, the lamp side will go open.

Is this correct?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2futhYR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to SE, Moley. There's a simple schematic button on the editor toolbar. Questions here usually get a quick response but I don't think we can figure out 85, 86, 87 and 30. A quick schematic might help. Start with a positive rail on top, negative on the bottom and fill in what information you know. Use the _Node_ symbol for your terminal / wire numbers.

Comment: Ah, I see. They're the standard DIN automotive pin numbers for relays. 85/86 are the coil, 87 is the normally open pin, 87A is the normally closed pin, and 30 is common. I'll try adding a diagram.

Answer (score 2):

You're saying the ABS logic has been reversed in that one system pulls low to indicate 'ABS on' and the other pulls low to indicate 'ABS off'. Your schematic is correct.

Good practice when switching a relay from an electronic device is to add a flyback diode to catch the negative inductive kick that the relay gives on turn-off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVEFog.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The complete circuit with lamp and guess of likely ABS unit internal transistor switch.*

Comment: Great, thanks very much. The relay I'll be using has a built in diode for this very purpose! Now - do I need to add a load (resistor) in series with the coil so that when the ABS module goes to ground there isn't a huge amount of current? Presumably when the circuit is working normally (factory) the lamp is the load. Cheers.

Comment: The coil resistance will limit the current. To be on the safe side let's assume that the transistor can switch 100 mA safely. From Ohm's Law we can calculate minimum coil resistance by \$R_{MIN} = \frac {V}{I_{MAX}} = \frac {12}{0.1} = 120 \Omega \$. Check with a multimeter.